# Why isn't chat more visible from the front page?

Tags: discussion, chat

I stumbled upon the chatrooms of Stack Overflow only after I had seen the "Talkative" badge whose description has a hyperlink taking you to the chatrooms:

> Post 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)

I looked all over the main page of Stack Overflow, and found no readily available way to access the chatrooms. Obviously, anyone who knows about the chatrooms can simply go to the [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) URL, but why isn't there a more accessible way from the main site? Shouldn't the chatrooms be displayed more clearly to promote people to join and have discussions?

Comment: It's also accessible from the burger menu, in between "help" and "logout".

Comment: This is more a generic problem of the hamburger menu being very unclear, IMO. It holds so many important things (including the log out which frequently pops up on meta too) yet it in no way invites you to click on it. Besides the fact that it is the SECOND hamburger menu in the same bar...

Comment: @Gimby I have to additionally point out that "the hamburger" has its title attribute set to: "A list of all 178 Stack Exchange sites". Not particularly indicative of the fact that there is chat, log out button, and sometimes a duplication of the user card (!) too...